# Is there any way to install GitHub Copilot in Visual Studio 2019 (not Visual Studio Code)?

Tags: visual-studio, github-copilot

I am looking in the marketplace but it seems only available for vscode?

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.copilot

Comment: try vs 2022 preview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GitHub Copilot now available for Visual Studio 2022
[https://github.blog/2022-03-29-github-copilot-now-available-for-visual-studio-2022/#:~:text=Once%20you%20have%20received%20an,install%20the%20GitHub%20Copilot%20extension](https://github.blog/2022-03-29-github-copilot-now-available-for-visual-studio-2022/#:%7E:text=Once%20you%20have%20received%20an,install%20the%20GitHub%20Copilot%20extension).

[Edit]
It is no more free now, You can have a free trial period of a month, then it is paid one.
[image]

[Edit - 10/09/2022]
It is available for Free (Education purpose)

1. For Students ([Link](https://dev.to/twizelissa/how-to-enable-github-copilot-for-free-as-student-4kal))
2. For Teachers ([Link](https://github.blog/2022-09-08-github-copilot-now-available-for-teachers/)).

Comment: As far as I know, it is free for students.

Comment: Question was VS2019, not VS2022. For sure, we didn't ask an advertisement. I've used Copilot in Pycharm Community for some months, but removed this again. The proposed code was inferior. Maybe in a few years it may improve. Also, I'm sure it's stealing+analysing my other code.

Answer (score 0):

No, not at the time... The only way is trying with Resharper, beacuase it uses the same base of IntelliJ, so you can install GitHub Copilot too

Answer (score -2):

[Github Copilot](https://copilot.github.com/) is currently only available as an extension for Visual Studio Code, with other integrated development environments to potentially follow.

Comment: Is it still not available for VS 2019 or 2022 ?

Comment: @Peck_conyon It's _only_ available for Visual Studio 2022 17.1 or later.