# Visual Studio Code extension alternative for GitHub copilot

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I recently came across GitHub copilot which finish the code and also give a short explanation of what is happening in the function, but there is a waiting list for us to use GitHub copilot. So I want to ask is there any more alternative which can do that for us?

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68323142/is-there-any-way-to-install-github-copilot-in-visual-studio-2019-not-visual-stu/71672239#71672239

Answer (score 1):

The waiting list have been removed now, you can try now.

Answer (score 1):

It's Oct.2022 now and Copilot is not free anymore. There is another open-source alternatives to it called CodeGeeX. The code is available at https://github.com/THUDM/CodeGeeX. Check out the VSCode extension at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aminer.codegeex

Also, the model weights can be applied and download.

Answer (score 1):

I started making free alternative to Github Copilot. I'm doing it on GPT3 API. I would like to raise some attention to this thing so I will be happy to receive your feedback on the github, as well as issues and maybe even pull requests :) This thing is already usable and saves me a lot of effort :) https://github.com/mrThomasTeller/vscode-gpilot